# Can WhatsApp convo be opened from browser?

Tags: php, whatsapp

I was checking online and there is no WhatsApp API but I was wondering if it would some how be possible to allow mobile numbers that are clicked on to open a WhatsApp convo with this number?

This leads to my second question if it would be possible to set up a confirmation link to be send to a user's WhatsApp number when they register on a site.

This would all be using a website by the way not a mobile application

Comment: So you want your site to send a confirmation link to a user via whatsapp?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑyeah I currently have an email confirmation link which already works but I wondered if there would be a way to do it via whatsapp

Comment: There is (*maybe*): https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=whatsapp+api&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @ʰᵈˑthank you will check it out now